# Where can I find the source code for the functions in math.h?

Tags: c, math, glibc

I want to see how math functions work, like `sin`, `cos`, `tan`, etc... Where can I find the source code? is it available locally or in the net?

Comment: In the source code for the run-time library for the specific compiler you're using. And don't assume it's going to be C source code.

Comment: What OS, what compiler?

Comment: One implementation you can find online is GNU glibc, at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/

Comment: I'm looking for a pure C implementation. glibc is mostly platform specific ASM.

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._

Answer (score 22, accepted):

fdlibm has pure C implementations of the math functions, with comments that explain the algorithms and give references for them. http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/