# What is the source code for C math library?

Tags: c, macos, math

I just started trying out C programming on macOS, and it looks like its using NVIDIA libraries for math. Is it closed source?

the below code compiles and runs on my m1 mac

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc == 1){
        printf("no args \n");
        return -1;
    }
    double x = atof(argv[1]);

    printf("log of %f is %f", x, log(x));
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

From the IDE when I search for definition of how log is implemented it took me to this:

```
__DEVICE__ float logf(float __a) {
  return __FAST_OR_SLOW(__nv_fast_logf, __nv_logf)(__a);
}
```

But I am not able to see the actual code that runs to compute the log
[image]

Comment: Usually, it's in libc (ie glibc on Linux).  I suggest you tag your platform, and also do you have a file name corresponding to your source code?  Unless you are using cuda I wouldn't expect nvidia code here.

Comment: A web search for "__FAST_OR_SLOW(__nv_fast_logf, __nv_logf)(__a);" finds some results -- seems to have something to do with Clang. I think if you follow some of those links you might find the source code.

Comment: Make sure you #include <math.h> and compile with -lm.

Comment: I have edited and added details, its an M1 mac, with VS code

Comment: Apple uses its own implementations for the standard C library math routines, so I doubt the Nvidia references are correct. Your IDE may have led you down a garden path. IDEs may have trouble navigating includes of platform headers due to potentially intricate dependencies on compile-time preprocessor identifier definitions. Way back when, Apple’s source code for the math library for Intel processors was open source and available at opensource.apple.com, but the new code for ARM processes is not. You could examine the assembly/machine code in a debugger.

Comment: [C library source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5214325/995714), [Where can I find the source code for the functions in math.h?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44212577/995714), [Where can I find the mathematical routines in GCC's source? How do the math functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61133705/995714)